# ¿Cómo imprimir en blade un array?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, blade

Tengo un array que no puedo imprimir en mi vista blade. Este es el código que tengo:

```
{
    "name":"ADRIROSAS POZO MOROCHO ADRIANA CRISTINA",
    "created_at":"2021-12-02T14:06:29.000000Z",
    "updated_at":"2021-12-28T16:41:23.000000Z",
    "marketer":null,
    "weight":[
        {
            "id":3,
            "large":"111",
            "width":"31",
            "high":"29",
            "average":"232",
            "created_at":"2022-02-16T20:34:58.000000Z",
            "updated_at":"2022-02-17T16:59:18.000000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

¿Cómo imprimo este código en la vista blade?

Esto es lo que estoy imprimiendo pero me da error:

```
{{ $item->weight->large }}
```

Error:

> Exception
> Property [large] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\laragon\www\app-ffc\resources\views\weightdistribution\index.blade.php)

Comment: Gracias por responder pero ya intente así, pero tampoco.

Comment: no te funciona con @foreach?
```
@foreach($array as $key => $value)
    Key: {{ $key }}    
    Value: {{ $value }} 
@endforeach
```

Comment: Buen día, el código que muestras de qué es? Un componente Blade? Un componente Livewire? Una modelo? etc... Necesitamos saber de dónde viene la información ya que la forma de hacerlo es un poco diferente. Por favor edita tu pregunta y pon el código completo de esa sección

Comment: `weight` es un array. Si el item es un objeto tendrías que usar la sintaxis `{{ $item->weight[0]->large }}`. Si es un array la sintaxis cambia, pero lo importante es que puede haber muchos weights. Tienes que llegar por un índice numérico antes de pedir el atributo "large"